# Unable to get full path to final binary in Xcode 4 using build variables

Tags: xcode4, build, mpi

I'm trying to run a command-line MPI program from within Xcode, which requires I run my program as so:

```
 /usr/bin/mpiexec -np 4 {my binary}
```

I'm trying to edit the scheme, using [the Xcode 4 docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef) and `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` from the command line as my guide to locate the proper variables. I have a scheme that runs mpiexec and passes the following arguments:

```
-np 4 $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$TARGET_NAME
```

Which, if I go by their values in `xcodebuild`, should give me this:

```
/Users/<excluding full path>/MyProject/build/Debug/MyTarget
```

However, when running inside Xcode, I get this:

```
build/Debug/MyTarget
```

Prefixing this as so:

```
-np 2 ${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}
```

results in the full path ***up to the first space in the path name*** and then nothing more, which tells me there may be some issue with space escaping.

which is not enough to allow mpiexec to locate my binary. What is the proper way to identify the absolute path of my built executable using Xcode schemes and arguments?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine if I do this:

```
 -np 2 "${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}"
```

Perhaps it just needed the double-quotes to avoid the space in the path?

I'm leaving this unaccepted for a while in case someone posts a proper answer, this feels like a hack to me